# Installed sata drive but I cannot see it when using command blkid

Tags: sata

I have ubuntu server running of usb flash drive. I installed sata drive connected everything and fired the server up, but I cannot find the new drive when using blkid command.

is there any other way to mount it?

p.s. I've no monitor, so cannot check bios settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm, without a monitor it's difficult to tell if the system is recognizing it. First, make sure you are using sudo as these will need elevated privileges. Secondly, try `sudo fdisk -l` as that should list all drives connected to the system.